# Proof of non-symmetry of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem in continuum mechanics wich can be reduced to a simple math problem:

Consider a in general non symmetric real invertible $3\times 3$ matrix $\boldsymbol{F}$ and a real $3\times 3$ matrix $\boldsymbol{P}$. Then the assertion is

$$\boldsymbol{P}\boldsymbol{F}^{\text{T}}=\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{P}^{\text{T}}\ \Longrightarrow\ \boldsymbol{P}^{\text{T}}\neq \boldsymbol{P}$$

So in other words: then $\boldsymbol{P}$ cannot be symmetric in general.

Background: $\boldsymbol{P}$ is a matrix representing the 1st Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensor and $\boldsymbol{F}$ is the deformation gradient. This assertion is to be found in any continuum mechanics book (Holzapfel, ...)

I am thankful for any help.

My ideas so far: it holds that the products $\boldsymbol{P}\boldsymbol{F}^{\text{T}}$ and $\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{P}^{\text{T}}$ are symmetric. If I can show that the product of a non-symmetric matrix with a symmetric matrix is not symmetric, then $\boldsymbol{P}$ cannot be symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, "the product of a non-symmetric matrix with a symmetric matrix is not symmetric" is not true. Counterexample :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1  &   1 &    0\\
     2   &  1  &   0\\
     0   &  0 &   1
\end{pmatrix}, \ \ 
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1  &   1 &    0\\
     1   &  2  &   0\\
     0   &  0 &   1
\end{pmatrix}$$

give the symmetric matrix :

$$AB=\begin{pmatrix}
2  &   3 &    0\\
     3   &  4  &   0\\
     0   &  0 &   1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: thanks, so I need another ansatz

Comment: Yes ; I have personaly no idea of how to attack directly this issue. Could you give references about other places where this question is found ?

Comment: It seems most of the mechanics community does not ask such questions. The assertion can be found e.g. here:
https://www.comsol.de/multiphysics/stress-and-equations-of-motion

or here

https://sameradeeb-new.srv.ualberta.ca/stress/first-and-second-piola-kirchhoff-stress-tensors/